# Fat Domain Models => Inefficient?

Tags: performance, repository, design-patterns, data-transfer

Looking at DDD, we abstract the database into the various models which we operate on and look at it as a repository where our models live.  Then we add the Data Layers and the Service/Business layers on top of it.  My question is, in doing so, are we creating inefficiencies in data transfer by building fat models?

For example, say we have system that displays an invoice for a customer on the screen.
Thinking of it in terms of OOP, we'd probably end up with an object that looks somewhat like this:

```
class Invoice {
    Customer _customer;
    OrderItems _orderitems;
    ShippingInfo _shippingInfo;
}

class Customer {
    string name;
    int customerID;
    Address customerAddress;
    AccountingInfo accountingInfo;
    ShoppingHistory customerHistory;
}
    (for the sake of the question/argument, 
    let's say it was determined that the customer class had to 
    implement AccountingInfo and ShoppingHistory)
```

If the invoice *solely* needs to print the customer name, why would we carry all the other baggage with it?  Using the repository type of approach seems like we would be building these complex domain objects which require all these resources (CPU, memory, complex query joins, etc) AND then transferring it over the tubes to the client.

Simply adding a customerName property to the invoice class would be breaking away from abstractions and seems like a horrible practice.  On the third hand, half filling an object like the Customer seems like a very bad idea as you could end up creating multiple versions of the same object (e.g. one that has a an Address, but no ShoppingHistory, and one that has AccountingInfo but no Address, etc, etc).  What am I missing, or not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As good object relational mappers can lazy load the relationships, you would therefore pull back the customer for your invoice, but ignore their accounting and shopping history. You could roll your own if you're not using an oject-relational mapper.

Often you can't do this within your client as you'll have crossed your trasaction boundary (ended your database trasaction) and so it is up to your service layer to ensure the right data has been loaded.

Testing the right data is available (and not too much of it) is often good to do in unit tests on a service layer.

Comment: Good point.  I think I must have not fully understood lazy loading >.<

Answer (score 0):

You say "it was determined that the customer class had to implement AccountingInfo and ShoppingHistory", so clearly displaying an invoice is NOT the only task that the system performs (how else was it "determined" that customers need those other functionalities otherwise?-).

So you need a table of customers anyway (for those other functionalities) -- and of course your invoice printer needs to get customer data (even just the name) from that one table, the same one that's used by other functionality in the system.

So the "overhead" is purely illusory -- it appears to exist when you look at one functionality in isolation, but doesn't exist at all when you look at the whole system as an integrated whole.